# Random number condition anomaly with AndEngine - Android

Tags: android, random, andengine, conditional-statements, physics

I'm currently using [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/), to do a little box game with faces in it, so that the player spawns faces when touching the screen. So here I already declared the variable "onch" as a double and I made it a random number between 1 and 4 so that each time addFace is called, it generates a new number and so a new face. However I'm getting always the last face. I'm getting only this :

```
face = new AnimatedSprite(pX, pY, this.mort, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
body = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, face, BodyType.DynamicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);
```

Here is the full code :

```
private void addFace(final float pX, final float pY) {
    onch = Math.floor((Math.random()*4)+1);

    final AnimatedSprite face;
    final Body body;

    if(onch == 4) {
        body = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, face, BodyType.DynamicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);
    } else if (onch == 3) {
        face = new AnimatedSprite(pX, pY, this.noel, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        body = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, face, BodyType.DynamicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);
    } else if (onch == 2) {
        face = new AnimatedSprite(pX, pY, this.sournois, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        body = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, face, BodyType.DynamicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);
    } else {
        face = new AnimatedSprite(pX, pY, this.mort, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        body = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, face, BodyType.DynamicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);
    }

    face.animate(200);

    this.mScene.attachChild(face);
    this.mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(face, body, true, true));
}
```

Why do I only receive the one value?

Answer (score 1):

i think it is because you set your variables with the

```
final
```

modifier, once you set an instance of a final variable it cannot be changed, so your random code works fine but since the variables have the final modifier, once they are set the first time they are stuck like that, you cannot change them

Comment: The method allows `final` modifier only, I tried to change it but it won't let me.

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with the code.

- This line `body = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, face, BodyType.DynamicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);` appears in the code **four** times. You could take it out of your `if` statements because it's the same in all four.
- As JRowan said, `final` should not be use in this case.
- Now, if you are sure that the face is exactly identical at the end of this method, the problem is in one of these calls: `AnimatedSprite()`constructor might give you the same face no matter what arguments you put in, **or** `animate()` method of `AnimatedSprite` class changes the `face` and makes it look the same in the end.

Answer (score -1):

This appears incorrect:

```
onch = Math.floor((Math.random()*4)+1);
```

Try:

```
onch = Math.floor((Math.random()%4)+1);
```

Comment: Oh, indeed. I did not take know `Math.Random` returned a double. I was more surprised he was not using `Random.nextInt()`.